# How to add custom C++ compiler flags to a conda-build flow?

Tags: c++, compiler-flags, conda-build

How do I inject my own desired C++ compiler flags into a `conda-build` flow?

I tried this, in my `conda_build_config.yaml` file:

```yaml
cxx_compiler:
  - gxx                        # [linux]
  - clangxx -Wno-c++11-narrowing  # [osx]
  - vs2019                     # [win]
```

And I got:

`conda.exceptions.InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '-Wno-c++11-narrowing_osx-64': invalid character(s)`

Then I tried this:

`CXXFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" conda build ...`

but I got the same error I was getting originally:

```
  kiva/agg/src/kiva_graphics_context_base.cpp:637:27: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'double' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
      double tmp[] = {0, 0, img->width(), img->height()};
```

So, I'm guessing my explicit setting of the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable is just being ignored by `conda-build`.
(Is that correct?)

Then, I tried this, in the `meta.yaml` file:

```
build:
  number: 3
  script: "CXXFLAGS='-Wno-c++11-narrowing' {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv "
```

But, I still got the same original error.

Digging deeper, I found the [*Inherited Environment Variables* section of the `conda-build` documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/user-guide/environment-variables.html#inherited-env-vars), which suggests doing this:

```yaml
build:
  {snip}
  script_env:
    - CXXFLAGS=-Wno-c++11-narrowing
```

But, I still get the same error when I try this.

**How does one get a custom compiler flag inserted into a `conda-build` flow?**

I think my last attempt above is actually doing what it's supposed to, because I find this line in my `~/miniconda3/conda-bld/enable_1680434176391/work/build_env_setup.sh` file:

`export CXXFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing"`

So, is the problem really that my build command:

`python -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv`

is ignoring the setting of the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! This (in the `meta.yaml` file) worked:

```yaml
build:
  {snip}
  script_env:
    - CFLAGS=-Wno-c++11-narrowing
```

Sure enough, [buried in the `conda-build` documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/user-guide/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-set-during-the-build-process) (Scroll to the end of the section.) I find this:

> The environment variables listed in the following table are defined only on macOS.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| CFLAGS | `-arch` flag |
| CXXFLAGS | Same as `CFLAGS` |

{snip}

If ever there was a candidate for a top-of-the-page "quick alert". :(

Answer (score -1):

To add custom C++ compiler flags in a conda-build process, bld.bat file (Windows) in the recipe directory. Add the desired flags to the CXXFLAGS environment variable in the build script. On Windows, add set CXXFLAGS=%CXXFLAGS% -Wno-c++11-narrowing to bld.bat. Ensure the build script uses CXXFLAGS when invoking the compiler, and then run the conda build.
hope it helps.

Comment: Can you expand upon this: "Ensure the build script uses CXXFLAGS when invoking the compiler"?